# Compiling hybrid classes (templated and untemplated functions) into a static library

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, static-libraries, inline

I'm writing a game engine lib, for the sake of science. I've written static libs successfully in the past, although there were no templated functions.

When dealing with templated functions, I use to sepparate their code from the untemplated ones. Templated functions code lie in the header file, while the others in the .cpp/.hpp file.

Below is a snippet of one of it's modules: signals.

```
// Connection.h
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

namespace mqs
{
    using Disconnector = std::function<void(std::uint32_t)>;

    class Connection final
    {
    public:
        explicit Connection(std::shared_ptr<mqs::Disconnector> disconnector, std::uint32_t index);

        bool connected() const;
        void disconnect() const;

    private:
        std::uint32_t index;
        std::weak_ptr<mqs::Disconnector> disconnector;
    };
}

// Signal.h
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "connection.hpp"

namespace mqs
{
    template <typename...>
    class Signal;

    template <typename R, typename... A>
    class Signal<R(A...)> final
    {
    public:
        Signal();

        template <typename Lambda>
        mqs::Connection connect(Lambda&& lambda) {
            slots.push_back(std::forward<Lambda>(lambda));
            return mqs::Connection(disconnector, slots.size() - 1U);
        }

        void operator()(A&&... args) const;

        unsigned connections() const;

    private:
        std::vector<std::function<R(A...)>> slots;
        std::shared_ptr<mqs::Disconnector> disconnector;
    };
}

// Connection.hpp
#pragma once
#include "connection.h"

namespace mqs
{
    Connection::Connection(std::shared_ptr<mqs::Disconnector> disconnector, std::uint32_t index) {
        this->index = index;
        this->disconnector = disconnector;
    }

    bool Connection::connected() const {
        return !disconnector.expired();
    }

    void Connection::disconnect() const {
        if (const auto& lock = disconnector.lock()) {
            lock->operator()(index);
        }
    }
}

// Signal.hpp
#pragma once
#include "signal.h"

namespace mqs
{
    template <typename R, typename... A>
    Signal<R(A...)>::Signal() {
        disconnector = std::make_shared<mqs::Disconnector>([this](std::uint32_t index) {
            slots.erase(slots.begin() + index);
        });
    }

    template <typename R, typename... A>
    void Signal<R(A...)>::operator()(A&&... args) const {
        for (auto& slot : slots) {
            slot(std::forward<A>(args)...);
        }
    }

    template <typename R, typename... A>
    unsigned Signal<R(A...)>::connections() const {
        return slots.size();
    }
}
```

It compiles and all, however one of the problems I've been dealing with, is that `mqs::Signal` (signal.hpp) cannot be included in different headers or it will cause a `function already has a body`. When including `signal.h` I get `unresolved external symbol` which makes sense.

I've also tried making `inline` all the functions defined in their .hpp files above.

Is there any way to achieve this other than using huge header-only approaches?

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out, you need to make the function templates `inline`. This is necessary because the templates first need to be instantiated to become compilable functions, and that means the compiler needs source code.

However, if you look at members like `Signal<R(A...)>::disconnector;`, you'll notice that they are not dependent on `R` or `A...`. Hence, you could move them to a non-template base class.

There's a fairly common convention to use the extension `.ipp` for implementation files that still need to be included, e.g. because they contain template code. These will typically be included by the corresponding `.hpp` file, just before the `#endif` of the header guard. Therefore an `.ipp` file doesn't need its own header guard.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample? That wasn't clear to me.